# relation between inductive dimension and topological dimension

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space, topological dimension of $X$ denote by $dim_{top}(X)$ and define $dim_{top}(X)\leq n$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ by open sets with diameter $\leq \epsilon$ such that every point belongs at most $n+1$ sets of $\mathcal{U}$.

Also inductive dimension of $X$ denote by $ind(X)$ and define

1)$ind(X)=-1$ if and only if $X=\emptyset$,

2) $ind(X)\leq n$ where $n=0\ldots, $ if every $x\in X$ and every open set $V$ of $x$ there exists an open set $U\subset V$ such that

$x\in U$ and $ind(FrU)\leq n-1$ where $Fr(U)$ is boundary of $U$.

what is the relation between $dim_{top}(X)$ and $ind(X)$?

please help me to know it.

Answer (score 2):

For separable metric spaces $\operatorname{ind}(X) = \dim(X)$, where $\dim(X)$ is the covering dimension which for compact metric spaces coincides with your $\dim_{\text{top}}$ (Using Lebesgue numbers for covers).

So they're all equal in your case. Read Hurewicz or Engelking on dimension theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you help me more. Which part? or which page?

Comment: @user479859 both are books wolly devoted to dimension theory. It's quite non-trivial to show that the dimensions coincide for separable metric spaces (Engelking's "theory of dimensions" does cover it in one chapter at the start ). Also, Jan van Mill's books on infinite-dimensional topology cover the basic facts and the coincidence theorem.